Skew-correction matrix is incorrect
I have a plane of best fit defined by normal $n$
[0.00823152, 0.02654408, 0.65999828]

from point $r_0$
[ 4.67652464, -6.05848115,  1.7004922 ]

I want to correct the following points $\boldsymbol{r_P}$ (that are not quite co-planar):
   [ 4.54036847, -6.47415716,  1.72001204],
   [ 4.54471036, -6.22421999,  1.70884943],
   [ 4.53723242, -5.98484918,  1.69939263],
   [ 4.5219595 , -5.72160472,  1.68663769],
   [ 4.49992544, -5.49383894,  1.67985443],
   [ 4.83014797, -5.65804847,  1.6860585 ],
   [ 4.80321792, -6.62080145,  1.72426357],
   [ 4.82238605, -6.37893279,  1.70687175],
   [ 4.83051733, -6.14411867,  1.70358496],
   [ 4.83478157, -5.88423807,  1.68933162]

They're skewed (z axis omitted in this depiction):

I want to make them look like a grid (informally: move the right column upward) by aligning them to the following two vectors $u$ and $v$ which have been calculated, seemingly correctly, by a separate k-means process:
[ 0.29519169 -0.15781189  0.0027413 ]
[ 0.01289013 -0.34613701  0.01285031]

I tried following this guide to perform u/v projection, so I calculated
$$e_1 = \frac u {|u|}$$
$$e_2 = \frac v {|v|}$$
$$t_1 = (\boldsymbol{r_P} - r_0) e_1 $$
$$t_2 = (\boldsymbol{r_P} - r_0) e_2 $$
This runs but doesn't produce the results I'm looking for; the skew gets worse:
   [-0.43783451,  0.07605911],
   [-0.19827793, -0.03803563],
   [ 0.02754392, -0.15755831],
   [ 0.27383631, -0.29523721],
   [ 0.48405802, -0.42210324],
   [ 0.42845081, -0.0534275 ],
   [-0.49722724,  0.3770244 ],
   [-0.26054935,  0.27975714],
   [-0.03455973,  0.17619832],
   [ 0.21456465,  0.05732198]


In an ideal scenario, I'd fix my linear algebra to take $u$ and $v$ (which will eventually change in value) to produce a 4x2 affine transformation matrix. Experimentally, with the above data, the matrix should look like
    (  3.0,  2.3),
    (  0.0,  4.0),
    (  0.0,  0.0),
    (-13.5, 15.5),

That includes a de-skew, translation and scale so that

most of the points are basically non-negative, with one at the origin; and
the points fall basically on integer coordinates.

After transformation:
 [ 1.21105407e-01  4.62188522e-02]
 [ 1.34131067e-01  1.05595386e+00]
 [ 1.11697260e-01  1.99623786e+00]
 [ 6.58784940e-02  3.01408795e+00]
 [-2.23688605e-04  3.87447274e+00]
 [ 9.90443913e-01  3.97714644e+00]
 [ 9.09653757e-01  6.41954256e-02]
 [ 9.67158157e-01  1.07575678e+00]
 [ 9.91551983e-01  2.03371519e+00]
 [ 1.00434470e+00  3.08304534e+00]

